# heroku: rails app won't deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am not sure how to desribe this.
I have an existing rails app. We have decided to try using Heroku as a test platform.
So I did:

```
heroku login
heroku create
git push heroku r31heroku
```

and get this:

```
git push heroku r31heroku
Counting objects: 4096, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2895/2895), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4096/4096), 1.91 MiB | 33 KiB/s, done.
Total 4096 (delta 2716), reused 1882 (delta 1123)
To git@heroku.com:ancient-falls-9918.git
 * [new branch]      r31heroku -> r31heroku
```

Basically... it writes it to somewhere on heroku but I don't get the magic lines:

```
-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
```

And then have it install bundler, etc etc.

What is it doing? It is like heroku is just a git repository and heroku is not seeing that I am deploying to it.

I have deleted and created a new heroku app twice with the same result. I have also created a brand new rails app and deployed that successfully to Heroku. So it is something about this app in particular.

I believe it has something to do with the git config, but how can I debug this further?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to push to the remote master.

```
git push heroku r31heroku:master
```

Comment: oh for the love of god. that little nugget is left out of their docs. Thank you very much!